# processing js / jquery / ajax - unable to load a sketch

Tags: jquery, ajax, processing

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
  var canvasRef = $('<canvas id="project_canvas"/>');
  var p = Processing.loadSketchFromSources(canvasRef, '/anything.pde');
  $('#loader').append(canvasRef);
});
```

To load a processing-js sketch using jquery / ajax and it's doing something weird - trying to break up all the characters of /anything.pde throwing this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/a 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/n 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/n 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/y 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/t 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/h 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/i 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/g 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/p 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/d 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8888/e 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be passes as an array:

```
var p = Processing.loadSketchFromSources(canvasRef, ['/anything.pde']);
```

As the name says loadSketchFromSources, Sources, you can pass multiple source as an array.

Comment: Ah nice - thanks - where is this function documented? Do you know how to set up a callback function?